# Make this function return true

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, patching

Sorry, I'm quite new to assembly, and I'm trying to make the code bellow return true:

```
.text:1000E3E0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:1000E3E0
.text:1000E3E0
.text:1000E3E0 ; bool __thiscall LicenseChecker::LicenseCheckerPlugin::hasValidLicense(LicenseChecker::LicenseCheckerPlugin *__hidden this)
.text:1000E3E0                 public ?hasValidLicense@LicenseCheckerPlugin@LicenseChecker@@QAE_NXZ
.text:1000E3E0 ?hasValidLicense@LicenseCheckerPlugin@LicenseChecker@@QAE_NXZ proc near
.text:1000E3E0                                         ; DATA XREF: .rdata:off_10024D68o
.text:1000E3E0                 mov     eax, [ecx+0Ch]
.text:1000E3E3                 mov     al, [eax+20h]
.text:1000E3E6                 retn
.text:1000E3E6 ?hasValidLicense@LicenseCheckerPlugin@LicenseChecker@@QAE_NXZ endp
.text:1000E3E6
.text:1000E3E6 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On a "crackme". I heard somewhere that 1 returns true, but no idea on how to do it.
I searched the web, but I simply couldn't understand what to do. I'm used to high-level programming languages, so assembly confuses me a lot.
Sorry for asking for such a simple thing.

Comment: can you provide the program containing this function?

Comment: @SYS_V Sorry, I didn't see your comment at the time. I formatted my PC, so I think I don't have it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy.

1. Check out the calling conventions that your binary follows;
2. Patch* with a **mov** of **1** to the register used for return values (most likely to be **rax** variant) before the **return** instruction : *mov rax, 1*;
3. Your function should return **1** all the time, regardless of whatever happens before the **return** instruction;

(*) Patching can be done manually using a hex editor or you can use OllyDBG or any tool that permits such transformations (check the web ;) ).

This is a simple and concise answer. If you wish more details, let me know.

Comment: It doesn't look like 64-bit code to me.

Comment: Sure, but does it matter? It's a proper answer to a very clear question. And, I have CLEARLY specified a : rax VARIANT (been there all the time, no edit).

Comment: mov eax,1 is also fine x64 code and will zero the higher part of rax anyway.

Comment: I agree, but I see it as a detail :)

Comment: It may not be such a trivial detail for someone "I'm quite new to assembly". It's a *tiny* change – just change *mov rax, 1* to `mov eax, 1`. (Looking at the current return value, it could even be just `mov al, 1`.)

Comment: "You" are not sure, but I am. If you do not agree, post a much better reply or edit mine; I've been teaching assembly for quite some time and can assure you that those tiny details are of no importance when the whole assembly programming logic isn't understood - which is the case here. Therefore, I'd rather have the person go look for themselves than provide a copy/paste answer.

Comment: In this case there appear to be enough bytes to overwrite with `mov eax, 1` or `mov al, 1` but there are many case where there are not enough bytes for that. In that case a way to make the return value 1 is to xor the register but itself (effectively making it 0) and increasing it by 1: `xor eax, eax` `inc eax`

Answer (score 0):

```
mov al, 0x1
test al, al
ret
```

In binary: `B0 01 84 C0 C3`

Set `al` to 1, then `AND` with itself. The result is always 1, so `ZF` is always zero. Quite trivial, but gets the job done. Patch at the beginning so you don't have to fill leftover bytes with `nop` instructions.